# Magento 2: The breadcrumbs changes

Tags: magento2

I am trying to modify my breadcrumbs, but problem is that I am unable to get all links. What I am trying to do is showing **selected menu** on left side and **Home / Primary Menu** on the right only Example
Selected category/Home/ category

. [Reference link](http://www.appareluae.com/company/)

[enter link description here](http://www.appareluae.com/company/)

```
<?php if ($crumbs && is_array($crumbs)) : ?>
<div class="breadcrumbs">
    <ul class="items">
        <?php foreach ($crumbs as $crumbName => $crumbInfo) : ?>
            <li class="item <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbName ?>">
            <?php if ($crumbInfo['link']) : ?>
                <a href="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $crumbInfo['link'] ?>" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['title']) ?>">
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
                </a>
            <?php elseif ($crumbInfo['last']) : ?>
                <strong><?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?></strong>
            <?php else: ?>
                <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($crumbInfo['label']) ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I think the URL you have shared is a WordPress website, not Magento2 website.

Comment: Yes but . I have to include this functionality in magento two.  can you help me . how to build this